# Example app request (Rails+MonogDB+Elasticsearch+Tire)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, elasticsearch, tire

Since there's almost no online tutorials for Tire in Rails with mongoDB
I just request a basic example rails app with search working and configured to mongoDB(e.g blog) and I'll trace the code myself. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this app here

https://github.com/cousine/bloggy